# Difference between the 2 dates on SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode12

I am trying to get the difference between the 2 dates, however, I keep getting an error message.

This is my code:

```
let fmt = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        
let date1 = fmt.date(from: "2017-08-06")!
let date2 = fmt.date(from: "2020-08-06")!

let diffs = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
        
Text(diffs)
```

I also imported foundation.

My error is Initializer `init(_:)` requires that `DateComponents` conform to `StringProtocol`.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues going on here:

1. With your current code, you will encounter a crash when trying to convert your date string to a date since it won't parse correctly and you're using `!`. This can be solved by formatting the string differently
2. You're trying to pass `DateComponents` to `Text`, which requires an input that conforms to `StringProtocol` (as the error says), which `DateComponents` does not. You can use `DateComponentsFormatter` to convert to a `String`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let fmt = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    private let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    
    var diffs : DateComponents {
        guard let date1 = fmt.date(from: "2017-08-06T00:00:00Z"),
              let date2 = fmt.date(from: "2020-08-06T00:00:00Z") else {
            return DateComponents()
        }
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(formatter.string(from: diffs) ?? "unknown")")
    }
}
```

If this component were re-rendered often, it would be a good idea to store the formatters somewhere that they wouldn't be recreated each time.

Comment: what do you mean by storing them somewhere??

Comment: Simplest answer would be to just declare them outside of the `View` (eg `let fmt = ...` at the root level of the file). You could also store them in a singleton.

Comment: thank you. Also is there any way I can convert the number to an int?

Comment: `Calendar.current.dateComponents` returns `DateComponents` which has `.day` which returns `Int?` -- I assume that's what you're looking for with an `Int`?

Comment: so if I wanted to get the hour as an int, I would turn the .day to .hour and write let hours = Int(diffs)?

Comment: You would change `.day` to `.hour` and then you'd get an `Int?` by doing `diffs.hour` -- to make it non optional, you'd have to optionally bind it, provide a default value, etc. Like `let intValue = diffs.hour ?? -1`